# (!!) operator with overflowing integer

Tags: haskell

I have just recently started learning Haskell and started playing around with the idea of infinite lists and lazy evaluation. I constructed an infinite list and tried to access an element at a very, very distant index using the `!!` operator. The issue is that the type signature for the `!!` operator is the following:

`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`

Which means it takes an `Int` as an index to retrieve that element from the list.

Now, my problem occurs whenever I try to index something so distant that it overflow the `Int` and therefore goes negative. What would then be the proper Haskell way of doing this?

Comment: On any modern system this would be very impractical anyway: `maxBound :: Int` is about 30 years in CPU clock cycles. Until you've got your result we likely have all 128-bit `Int`, and with those you'd have to wait longer than the age of the universe until you get an overflow...

Comment: @leftaroundabout You would be surprised to find out that this is not the case. The below solution worked quite well for me.

Comment: On a 32-bit platform you're of course quickly on the limits of `Int`. On 64 bit, no way. (None of this is specified by the Haskell standard, so even if all platforms had 256 bits your question would be valid. But it's perfectly ok that `Prelude.!!` has that signature, that's my point. In particular, any finite list that's completely stored in memory needs to fit in virtual memory, which is basically adressed by `Int`, so it's kind of crazy to use `Integer`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data.List.genericIndex supports using any Integral number to index, so you can use Integer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `!!` yourself with `Integer` instead of `Int`:

```
(!!!) :: [a] -> Integer -> a
xs     !!! n | n < 0 =  error "negative index"
[]     !!! _         =  error "index too large"
(x:_)  !!! 0         =  x
(_:xs) !!! n         =  xs !!! (pred n)
```